# urlrewrite last rule is not stopping

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter, urlrewriter

I have following url rewrite configuration:

**web.xml**:

```
<!--URL_REWRITE FILTER-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>

    <!-- sets up log level (will be logged to context log)
    can be: slf4j, TRACE, DEBUG, INFO (default), WARN, ERROR, FATAL,
    sysout:{level} (ie, sysout:DEBUG)
    if you are having trouble using normal levels use sysout:DEBUG
    (default WARN) -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>DEBUG</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- you can disable status page if desired
    can be: true, false (default true) -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>statusEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**urlrewrite.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
        "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">

<!--http://cdn.rawgit.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/master/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html-->

<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <name>Home</name>
        <from>^/$</from>
        <to>/index.html</to>
    </rule>

    <rule>
        <name>Api Versioning</name>
        <note>The plan is to keep api versioning logic here (i.e. fallback and old version support), so that developer
            doesn't have to worry
        </note>
        <from>^/v1/(.*)$</from>
        <to last="true">/api/$1</to>
    </rule>

    <rule>
        <name>Block Direct API access</name>
        <from>^/api/(.*)$</from>
        <to>/bla/$1</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

When I try to access `http://localhost:8080/v1/ping`, I am getting `Problem accessing /bla/ping. Reason:Not Found`.

Here are the logs:

```
2016-12-15 01:31:41.553:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ServerNameMatcher DEBUG: looking for hostname match on current server name localhost
2016-12-15 01:31:41.554:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: checking for status path on /v1/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.556:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: processing request for /v1/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.557:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Home (rule 0) run called with /v1/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.558:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Api Versioning (rule 1) run called with /v1/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.558:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: matched "from"
2016-12-15 01:31:41.561:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.substitution.MatcherReplacer DEBUG: found 1
2016-12-15 01:31:41.561:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.substitution.MatcherReplacer DEBUG: replaced sb is /api/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.566:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleExecutionOutput DEBUG: needs to be forwarded to /api/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.566:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: rule is last
2016-12-15 01:31:41.568:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ServerNameMatcher DEBUG: looking for hostname match on current server name localhost
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: checking for status path on /api/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: processing request for /api/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Home (rule 0) run called with /api/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Api Versioning (rule 1) run called with /api/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Block Direct API access (rule 2) run called with /api/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: matched "from"
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.substitution.MatcherReplacer DEBUG: found 1
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.substitution.MatcherReplacer DEBUG: replaced sb is /bla/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleExecutionOutput DEBUG: needs to be forwarded to /bla/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ServerNameMatcher DEBUG: looking for hostname match on current server name localhost
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: checking for status path on /bla/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: processing request for /bla/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.569:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Home (rule 0) run called with /bla/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.570:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Api Versioning (rule 1) run called with /bla/ping
2016-12-15 01:31:41.570:INFO:/:qtp1686100174-51: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Block Direct API access (rule 2) run called with /bla/ping
```

How to make url rewrite to stop at rule marked `last`.

Comment: I think it actulay stop, but after rule marked last - it go into new cycle. And here the next rule work. I see two variants: 1. In the last rule regexp - make escape of the strings with substrig **api**. 2. Or you can add to the previous rule type="forward", and delete `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` in the **web.xml** inside UrlRewriteFilter filter-mapping tag.